# uitableview absolute row position

Tags: uitableview, row

i'd like to know if is possible to know the absolute row position in a tableview including several sections ...
i mean
section 0
   row 0
   row 1
section 1
   row 0 (absolute 2)
   row 1 (absolute 3)

etc. etc.

tnx a lot

Answer (score 2):

You could always just count it yourself. If you want the absolute position of the cell at [mySection, myRow], you could do...

```
int mySection, myRow; // obtained via however...
int absRow = 0;
for(int i=0; i<mySection; ++i) {
    absRow += [myTableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}
absRow += myRow;
```

Comment: This can crash if you don't take care to validate that the `mySection` and `MyRow` values are in bounds of the `UITableView` instance

Answer (score 0):

For a more complete solution, consider this gist:

https://gist.github.com/piterwilson/d2db8acb46a376274e2a6e1d74364af2